# Automating Qt build - Submodule issue. Can not get a clean working directory

Tags: git, qt, git-submodules

I want to automate the build process for specific Qt versions. According to the [Qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Getting_the_submodule_source_code) the commands for this are

```
git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
git checkout v5.9.0
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This worked and the result was a clean working directory with version 5.9.0 checked out. Now i checked out version 5.8.0 with the commands

```
git checkout v5.8.0
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

During the update there were some warnings that some directories could not get removed because they are not empty. And now the result of `git status` looks like this

```
HEAD detached at v5.8.0
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   qtdeclarative (untracked content)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        qtremoteobjects/
```

In the [Qt Wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Cleaning) the cleaning process is stated as

```
git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx" && git clean -dfx
```

When executing this command there are messages that some directories are skipped - But not stated why. Therefore the working directory still contains untracked content.

Anyone knows which magical commands work to really get a clean working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you carefully read the manpages of [`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) you will see that it states:

> Git will refuse to delete directories with .git sub directory or file unless a second -f is given.

Therefore to really get a clean directory tree you have to do the cleanup like this

```
git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dffx" && git clean -dffx
```

This will remove the repositories completetly though. So if you switch to another version which contains the submodule - It has to be cloned again.